# Database Architecture, Database Split

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, data-vault

I have come across DB architecture which does not feel right to me. It is for a small team of developers... I would appreciate any opinion on this design.

This is a simplified description of the system. All of the 3rd NF databases (Client, Accounting, Rate, Exposure)

We have 4 Normal Form DBs:

•   *Client DB*: maintain client & organisation info

•   *Rate DB*: getting exchange rates from a 3rd party system

•   *Exposure DB*: contacting a 3rd party system for getting our bank account 
and trade info

•   *Accounting DB*: further calculation on the financial risk and forecasting

We have the following databases for data wharehousing

•   *SQL Server Analysis Services*: Star Schema

•   *Cube*

**Database Split:**
Our 4 Databases (*Client*, *Rate*, *Exposure*, *Accounting*) are split amount 4 SQL Servers, but they all run on the same physical server. These databases need the data from eachother, for example we have an Organisation Table which is used in all DBs… or Rates are needed in other DBs.

**Analysis Services:**
We have a star schema and Analysis Services. My understanding is that *Data Vault* could be used as a source for generating Start Schema…. But we are not using our *Data Vault* for that purpose. We use SSIS to read the data directly from *Client, Rate, Exposure and Accounting* DBs and populate start schema directly.

**Question:**

1. Is Splitting databases a good idea when we need to use the data within those splitted Databases?
2. Is there a good Source/Blog to explain when it is a good idea for splitting a database?
3. Is copying tables from source database to destination database a good solution? I feel cross DB queries would be much more simple and efficient than copying so many tables into multiple DBa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether something is a good idea is a question of opinion.  What is less so is a question of what the tradeoffs are, and here I can discuss those.

Splitting databases between departments gives departments greater freedom in deciding their domain models.  One of the valid insights of the DDD school of thought is that teams form bounded contexts which may use vocabulary in a way slightly different than others.  If giving the various teams more flexibility in deciding their own terminology and data models is a positive thing, that is going for this.

On the other hand, there are a number of performance drawbacks.  Each system knows less about the data distribution in each database, and therefore is less able to effectively plan.  Cross-node joins are *always* expensive. So you get some real downsides as well.

I think copying data tends to work against the bounded context advantages of division btw and that is a warning.  But then this is a tradeoff between autonomy and performance.

A couple other things to consider:

1. Would linked servers be a better option than a data vault?
2. Would some sort of ETL controlled by the destination database be better?

Answer (score 2):

There's a common challenge in designing solutions that cross domain boundaries. If you have a single database with every domain object, everything becomes dependent on each other; if you have lots of independent databases, you have to deal with cross-domain queries.

The most up-to-date thinking on this is the concept of [micro services](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) and [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). Arguably, your design is a primitive form of this design solution, with the "data vault" acting as a broker.

The decision the microservices architecture enforces is "independence is more important than efficiency". Each microservice (and underlying data store) can do what makes sense, and move at its own speed without worrying about dependencies. The price for that is a more complex solution, especially when dealing with data dependencies.

Comment: It is worth noting that CQRS is not without controversies even in the DDD camp.  It makes sense in some cases, but not in others.  And micro services run the risk of redoing the same mistakes we saw with DCOM and CORBA just over HTTP.